# Add a counter by date, user per day to a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of data which stores scans into a building, and this contains well over a million rows of data. I am attempting to add a temporary status column within this query, which **counts the scans on a daily basis**. For the purpose of this question lets use this as the main data table:

```
CREATE TABLE DataTable (DataTableID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
User VARCHAR(50),
EventTime DATETIME)
```

from this I have narrowed it down to show only the scans for today:

```
SELECT * FROM DataTable 
WHERE CONVERT(DATE,EventTime) = CONVERT(DATE, SYSDATETIME())
```

It is at this point in which I want to add a status column to this query above. The Status column:

- WHEN **ODD** - will mean that the person **is in** the building
- WHEN **EVEN** - will mean that the person **is not** in the building

  (This is simply an integer field which starts on 1, and will increment by 1 per scan on that day, **PER USER**). ***How would I go about doing this?***
- I do want to make this a view after so its worth mentioning in case this affects the query syntax
- Also its worth mentioning that I cant add a status column to the main table as this would prevent the door access program working, otherwise I would add something in here to control that.

EXAMPLE DATA:

```
DataTableID         User            EventTime              Status
     1              Joe             30/08/2016 09:00:00      1
     2              Alan            30/08/2016 08:45:00      1
     3              John            30/08/2016 09:02:00      1
     4              Steven          30/08/2016 07:30:00      1
     5              Joe             30/08/2016 11:00:00      2
     6              Mike            30/08/2016 17:30:00      1
     7              Joe             30/08/2016 12:00:00      3
```

Comment: please show some sample data and expected result  as text ,explain with examples not words

Comment: what about "SELECT <whatever you want> as "Status" FROM DataTable 
WHERE CONVERT(DATE,EventTime) = CONVERT(DATE, SYSDATETIME())"

Comment: What is supposed to be *in* this status column?

Comment: Looking at your example data, are you wanting the status column to increment based upon the field 'User'?

Comment: additional information added explaining how this works. if you could please remove the negative marks against the question or expand on additional information you would like to be included then Ill add it above

Comment: yes Rich Benner, this will increment by 1 per user, I have now added that above in the main question body

Comment: But Mike doesn't have any status with a value of 1

Comment: well spotted, my bad! ill amend now

Comment: @Crezzer7 ok, thanks for clarifying. I've posted an answer below, take a look to see if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a simple windowing function for this. Take a look at the query below and let me know if you have any questions. This is ordered by EventTime rather than DataTableID for the windowing, it's then ordered by DataTableID in the final query. This is going to make sure you don't have any issues if your data isn't in the correct order in the table.

Temp table for testing;

```
CREATE TABLE #DataTable 
(DataTableID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[User] VARCHAR(50),
EventTime DATETIME)
```

Fill it with sample data;

```
INSERT INTO #DataTable
VALUES
 ('Joe', '2016-08-30 09:00:00')
,('Alan', '2016-08-30 08:45:00')
,('John', '2016-08-30 09:02:00')
,('Steven', '2016-08-30 07:30:00')
,('Joe', '2016-08-30 11:00:00')
,('Mike', '2016-08-30 17:30:00')
,('Joe', '2016-08-30 12:00:00')
```

Query

```
SELECT 
DataTableID
,[User]
,EventTime
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [User] ORDER BY EventTime) Status
FROM #DataTable 
WHERE CONVERT(DATE,EventTime) = CONVERT(DATE, SYSDATETIME())
ORDER BY DataTableID
```

Output

```
DataTableID User    EventTime               Status
1           Joe     2016-08-30 09:00:00.000 1
2           Alan    2016-08-30 08:45:00.000 1
3           John    2016-08-30 09:02:00.000 1
4           Steven  2016-08-30 07:30:00.000 1
5           Joe     2016-08-30 11:00:00.000 2
6           Mike    2016-08-30 17:30:00.000 1
7           Joe     2016-08-30 12:00:00.000 3
```

Comment: thankyou for the answer, I shall work my way through this now and get back to you shortly

Comment: that does the trick! thankyou very much for your help, next time ill add more details to the question straight away to avoid any confusion!

Comment: Happy to help. More clarification on the original question would probably avoid the down votes (from others) next time. We live and learn though :)

Comment: I know! rushing it to get it done didn't help haha, but thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
select *, row_number() over(partition by user, cast(eventtime as date) order by eventtime) as status
from datatable
```

should do the trick.

However, I'd suggest to create a calculated column as cast(eventtime as date), and compound index on this and user column and the original eventtime column as well for performance reasons.